# Laravel vue Column not found: 1054 Unknown

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to send array of id's to back-end and store them with `sync` method but it returns

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `category_products` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `0`) values (0, 12, 2))
```

## Code

`product model`

```
public function categories(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_products', 'product_id', 'category_id');
}
```

`category model`

```
public function products(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

`controller store function`

```
//getting other inputs...
$product->save();
$product->categories()->sync($request->categories, false);
```

`data that sent to back-end`

[image: one]

> Note: probably it's worth to mention that i am using vueJs to sending
>   data and it's not blade based.

`Component HTML`

```
<el-cascader
    v-model="form.categories"
    style="width: 100%;"
    :options="cats"
    :props="{
        multiple: true,
        checkStrictly: true,
        value: 'id',
        label: 'name',
    }"
    clearable
    filterable>
</el-cascader>
```

`Component Script`

```
data() {
    return {
        brands: [],
        cats: [],
        tags: [],
        site_name: process.env.MIX_APP_NAME,
        site_url: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
        dialogImageUrl: '',
        dialogVisible: false,
        disabled: false,
        form: {
            name: '',
            slug: '',
            price: '',
            new_price: '',
            sku: '',
            qty: 1,
            active: '',
            photo: '',
            photos: [],
            shortDesc: '',
            longDesc: '',
            tags: [],
            brand_id: '',
            categories: [], // this will send to back-end
            user_id: '',
            seoTitle: '',
            seoTags: '',
            seoPhoto: '',
            seoDescription: '',
            variations: [],
            options: [],
            condition: '',
            isbn: '',
            ean: '',
            upc: '',
        },
    }
},
methods: {
    // send product data
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${await this.$auth.getAccessToken()}`
        axios.post('/api/admin/products/store', this.form)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.success);

            this.$notify({
                title: 'Hooray!',
                message: res.data.success,
                offset: 100,
                type: 'success'
            });

            // this.$router.push({name: 'adminProducts'});
            this.form = {
                name: "",
                slug: "",
                price: "",
                new_price: "",
                sku: "",
                qty: '',
                active: "",
                photo: "",
                shortDesc: "",
                longDesc: "",
                tags: [],
                brand_id: "",
                categories: [],
                seoTitle: "",
                seoTags: [],
                seoPhoto: "",
                seoDescription: "",
                variations: [],
                user_id: this.form.user_id
            };
        })
        .catch(error => {
            var errors = error.response.data;
                let errorsHtml = '<ol>';
                $.each(errors.errors,function (k,v) {
                        errorsHtml += '<li>'+ v + '</li>';
                });
                errorsHtml += '</ol>';

            this.$notify.error({
                title: 'Error',
                dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
                message: errorsHtml
            });
        })
    },
}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

I have fixed my issue with this code

```
foreach($request->categories as $caat){
  $product->categories()->sync($caat, false);
}
```

now it saves my product categories but personally not happy with it! I'd like to use default sync method `$product->categories()->sync($request->categories, false);`
 without any looping requires.

*Please share your ideas.*

Answer (score 0):

Its because your categories array is a two dimensional array. Now when your syncing that data your code looks like this.

```
$product->categories()->sync([0] => ['0' => ''], false);
```

that is why the error says, `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'`.

Now, to solve your problem, first your categories value must like this

```
$categories = [2, 1]; // like this one
$categories = [[2], [1]]; // not this one
```

You may re structure first your categories array before you sync, by doing this

```
$categories = [];
foreach ($request->categories$key => $category) {
       $categories [] = $category[0];
}

$product->categories()->sync($categories, false);
```